# Do operating systems warn you on SMART failure?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Are there operation systems that actually honor the results of SMART out of the box and tell the user to change the drive? Do they even do SMART test runs on their own?

Comment: Note that there is one layer in between: BIOSes can enable/disable SMART. Just yesterday I encountered a Dell machine where SMART was disabled in the BIOS. In that case, neither can the OS do anything with it ;-)

Comment: These superuser posts suggest Windows does not: http://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7 and http://superuser.com/questions/14803/what-is-the-easiest-method-of-checking-smart-status-for-your-hard-drive

Comment: @JanDoggen - Windows 7 already has the ability to detect errors so it doesn't matter.  When I experienced a failing hdd Windows was first to report it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Windows 7 or Vista you get this message if it detects a SMART error:

[image]

Windows operating systems before Vista don't check SMART status at all and will simply show a lot of 'disk' errors in Event Viewer before finally grinding to a halt, or possibly bluescreening.

Comment: Microsofts understanding of the word 'details' is a bit superficial ;-) [or is your screen shot cut off?] Well, we can always start a utility that lists the details or look in event viewer after this.