# Seagate harddrive: unable to mount

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, mount, data-recovery

I have a notebook with a Seagate Momentum 5400.6 in it. Suddenly it stopped working, only giving strange errors when trying to boot windows. I booted with an Ubuntu DVD, but Ubuntu couldn't fing the hard drive. So I tried putting it into an external case, and mount it through USB.

But same problem here: The hard drive is not mounted. I tried it on a MacBook, DiskUtility shows the disk (500.11GB ST950032...), three partitions (`disk3s1`, `System Reserved` and `disk3s3`), and that's it. The `System Reserved` takes a bit time to show up. When I try to mount one of the others, it says, that it couldn't be mounted.

The sound of the harddrive's spin sounds good, no clicking, beeping... Any ideas, how I can mount this harddrive?

Comment: Switch up the power/data cables, they might be the problem. Or the mobo port.

Comment: Which filesystem is used on the drive?

Comment: @Raystafarian I don't think the cables are the problem, because the external usb case works with other hard drives and therefore, the motherboard ports can't be the problem.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae the filesystem is NTFS

Comment: I'm confused. You used the same case & cables for a different disk on the same computer, same OS, same mobo connection? And you also used the current disk with the same configuration on a different machine?

Comment: No, the hard disk was inside a laptop; I dismounted it from the laptop, and put it in an external usb hard drive case. The harddisk doesn't work inside the motherboard (as I described using a bootable Ubuntu DVD, which couldn't mount the hdd), and it doesn't work when trying to connect it as an external usb device

Comment: In Ubuntu, what does lsusb say? Does it identify the disk? If it does, can you try to mount it with sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt, where X is the mount letter, could be a,b,c... (make sure you have the right letter by checking contento of mounted drive in /mnt).

Comment: Check the [smart](http://superuser.com/questions/14803/what-is-the-easiest-method-of-checking-smart-status-for-your-hard-drive) status of the disk, it might be dying even without clicking, beeping, etc.