# Need help diagnostic my PC freezes

Tags: windows-7, windows

Sometimes my PC freezes for a minute or two, nothing can be done at this time. After some time, it unfreezes and works normally. There are no error messages in the event log. This seems to be happening completely randomly. I have all the latest drivers and updates.
Ideas?

Comment: press the CAPS LOCK key during this freeze. Does the light on the keyboard toggle?

Comment: @magicandre1981, I'll try this next time it happens.

Comment: Check S.M.A.R.T. for HDD problems.

Comment: I have the same problem and have had it for many months, also with Windows 7. The freeze lasts 1-2 minutes and like you I find no record of it anywhere in the event log. Happens on average once a day (but not every day nor at same time each day).

Comment: I have Gigabyte GA-890GPA-UD3H m'board, onboard ATI Radeon HD4290 graphics, AMD Phenom II X6 1050T CPU, ADATA SSD S510 120GB, 4GB DDR3, Intel Gigabit CT Desktop Ethernet Adapter (I changed to this from onboard ethernet to try to fix this problem, but it didn't help). Does any of your hardware match?

Comment: @magicandre1981, caps lock works.

Comment: @Virus_7, what problems I should check and how?

Comment: @gogoud, none of this matches though I have a Radeon video, too. But mine is R9 285. i5-3550, P8Z77-I DELUXE/WD mobo, 16Gb RAM, Kingston SSD + Seagate HDD.

Comment: [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/a/15205)

Comment: @DavidPostill I checked my SMART data, as well as my system SSD I have 2 HDDs for backup/data. The SSD and 1 of HDDs give all ok, the 2nd HDD gives 'warning' for 'Reallocated Sector Count' and 'Reallocated Event Count', and 'attention' for 'Interface CRC Error Count'. This drive however isn't normally used by Windows (though it can access it). Could this be a cause of these freezes?

Comment: @DavidPostill, it shows "Health status ok" for both drives. However, 2 lines are shown in yellow for the HDD - "spin retry count" and "B8 unknown attribute". Not sure what this could mean.

Comment: reallocated rectors would cause Windows to spend time waiting on I/O events to be completed.  Sounds like you have discovered the source of the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, HDD is supposed to replace bad sector with good one, isn't it? So, this means every freeze is a newly died sector?

Comment: @user626528 - HDD will attempt to move the file to a good sector, and attempt to find a sector that can replace it, all my comment explained was that Windows spends time waiting on the HDD.  Its time to replace the HDD

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried Check Disk? 
Have you checked the integrity of the RAM?
There is the Windows Memory Diagnostics Tool and many other free bits of software to check the integrity of the RAM.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).