# HDD gets inacessible on Windows shutdown

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, bios

Windows is functional, i.e. it can be loaded. (Windows 7)
However, after shutting computer down, if I try to switch it on again, I get the error message with status 0xc000000e, info "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible."
This error persists through multiple reboots.

To successfully launch computer again I have to enter bios settings and exit them. Even if no changes to parameters are made, the windows now boots ok. "no keyboard" error message from bios seems to allow the launch too. (If you pull the keyboard wire out.)

Last software installations were openhardwremonitor-v0.7.1-beta http://openhardwaremonitor.org/ and RealTemp_370 https://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2089/real-temp-3-70/.
I'm a bit worried about the former, as I've tried to use its onstartup functionality. Yet I'm not sure that the problem wasn't present before the installation. Currently both programs are removed. (Their startup options were disabled before removal.)

The motherboard is ASUS P8Z77-m, BIOS version 1206.
The HDD is WDC WD10EARX-00N0YB0.
Windows is 7 corporate.

I've tried making new boot sector records in system recovery command line. I've tried reverting Windows to earlier state. (Prior to above mentioned installations) (19 September state of critical windows updates.)

What should I do now to get it working normally?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem not software.  The hardware problem of course being it appears your HDD has started to fail.  The current method your using sounds like it is just pure luck, and works, for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about software you installed within the OS - from what you're describing, you're not even getting that far.

Additional troubleshooting steps:

- Ensure your drive isn't failing ([check SMART](https://superuser.com/questions/14803/what-is-the-easiest-method-of-checking-smart-status-for-your-hard-drive), [check file system structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK), check with [Western Digital's diagnostics](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx)).
- Ensure your PSU isn't failing (test with a known-good replacement).
- Upgrade your BIOS to the [latest version](https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/P8Z77M/HelpDesk_Download/) (currently version 2105), reset it to defaults, and reconfigure it as needed.
- [Replace the BIOS/CMOS battery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao866I9XpTo).

Comment: Well, drive seems to pass the checks. (At least from all that numbery stuff it puts out as result of test, I don't see anything about "ur disk is ded")
Bios battery replacement did not solve the problem.
This is lab computer not my own and thus I'm not really enthusiastic about firmware update which feels risky somewhat.
I'll see whether other PSU will do any good.

Comment: It's been a while. I've finally got around to fix that computer.
I've failed to notice and mention that before but the computer had **two** drives, one of which was sdd. A known "system on ssd everything else elsewhere" scheme (failed on the second part btw).  
All methods from the list were tried.
The bios update was the scary one, so was done last. But it was indeed the solution.