# Gaming computer slow, mainly after login

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, drivers, performance

I'm using an MSI GP60 2PE Leopard running Windows 7 Ultimate x64. It has gotten a bit slugging, but it is very slow and prone to freezing 1 or 2 minutes after logging in. The hard drive light is on constantly during this period. To make things even worse, this is a gaming computer, which shouldn't really be having these problems. So it's either start up programs or drivers that are causing problems.

One time I made a new partition and installed windows 10 on it. It was running smoothly. But then I ran the driver installation disk that came with the laptop on windows 10, and I noticed the frame rate decreased. So drivers seem to be the main culprit.

I went back into windows 7 and opened up device manager and checked how many drivers there were. Nothing seemed out of the ordinary, until I came across the system devices. There were 35 drivers installed there.

[image]
[image]

More info: Chrome takes half a minute to get ready after first run on windows session.

Edit: Games run smoothly and don't seem to be affected by this problem.
Edit: The computer runs snappily after the hard drive calms down.
Disabling Superfetch (made sure it didn't re enable after reboot) didn't speed up boot. Here was the disk i used to install drivers:

[image]

Comment: Start with Process explorer. can you find the process generating the IO? failing that Filemon or Procmon should give you some idea. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Comment: "It has gotten a bit slugging, but it is very slow and prone to freezing 1 or 2 minutes after logging in." indicates an HDD I/O problem. "There were 35 drivers installed there." what is odd about that?

Comment: @Ramhound So it's normal to have 35 drivers under system devices?

Comment: the disk IO activity can be caused by superfetch service

Comment: Check your hard drive for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: @FluorescentGreen - Its not unusual.

Comment: @FrankThomas I set Process Explorer to run at startup. And the first thing i saw on it was a spike. I hovered over it and it said Steam.exe. 5 minutes later, another spike which said Skype.exe. Is steam and skype known for computer startup slowdowns?

Comment: well, you said your case IO light was on solid, so that doesn't indicate discrete spikes. can you see the IO activity that accounts for the light?

Comment: @magicandre1981 i have disabled superfetch and it hasn't helped. guys you have to remember the suspicion lies in the installer disk i used: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jaw4k.jpg

Comment: Install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx also works for win7),run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration**can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Win7 and captures the Disk activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes of activity after boot. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5U7QaUZvUenUTczaHlQVFFVc0E/view?usp=sharing    also while the problem is still there, my computer is working faster during busy hard drive than is was before

Comment: any update on it?

Comment: the problem of a computer being slow is minimal now, without uninstalling Trend Micro. Trend Micro has already been paid for and I don't know that many other good AV's out there, so switching to a new AV is not going to be a good idea. i dont want to have to replace my hard drive as i have lots of stuff i don't want to bother transferring and ssd's don't come cheap. unless you know anything about the msi driver utilities disc affecting performance, i don't think there is anything left to do

Answer (score 0):

I [checked the trace with WPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis) and I can see that `coreServiceShell.exe` causes a lot of DiskIO. I see that the file `coreServiceShell.exe` belongs to `Trend Micro Anti-Malware`. So uninstall Trend Micro and try a different Av suite.

[image]

To really speedup your gaming laptop, replace the WD Blue 2.5" HDD with an SSD.