# Many Transition from drive PhyRdy to PhyNRdy causing latencies in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, latency

My old Windows 7 pro sp1 laptop is becoming slow.
It freezes randomly for between 1 and 3 seconds before displaying a context menu, or when switching between windows.

After long searches, I suspect the hard drive, but Windows doesn't report any error.
**Smartctl** shows me that the **Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy SATA Phy Event counter is increasing fast** (about once per second) :

```
C:\windows\system32>smartctl -l sataphy /dev/sda
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [i686-w64-mingw32-win7(64)-sp1] (sf-6.4-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  4            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  4            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  4            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  4            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  4            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  4            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  4        31518  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
[...]
```

Should I worry about this high value for the **Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy counter** ?
(I don't know what this counter means exactly)

Thanks for any information.
More info about the laptop :
Model : HP Probook 4720s
Hard drive : TOSHIBA MK3261GSYN

**Edit :** complete report for smartctl -x :

```
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [i686-w64-mingw32-win7(64)-sp1] (sf-6.4-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MK..61GSY[N]
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK3261GSYN
Serial Number:    41H4D37SB
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 33a70426b
Firmware Version: MH000C
User Capacity:    320 072 933 376 bytes [320 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jan 18 15:24:51 2016 PM
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     128 (minimum power consumption without standby)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  64) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   100   100   050    -    0
  2 Throughput_Performance  POS--K   100   100   050    -    0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO---K   100   100   002    -    1252
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2132
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   073   073   010    -    563
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR-K   100   100   050    -    0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   P-S--K   100   100   050    -    0
  9 Power_On_Minutes        -O--CK   071   071   000    -    193h+48m
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--CK   142   100   030    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2125
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   100   100   001    -    0
184 End-to-End_Error        PO--CK   100   100   097    -    0
185 Unknown_Attribute       -O--CK   100   100   001    -    65535
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
189 High_Fly_Writes         -O-RCK   100   100   001    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   060   050   040    -    40 (Min/Max 14/42)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    57
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O---K   100   100   000    -    983055
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   085   085   000    -    151941
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    59
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O     51  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O     64  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Queued Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (64 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     11628         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  2
SCT Version (vendor specific):       1 (0x0001)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    41 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     14/42 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     10/50 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/60 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:            0/60 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    478 (449)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
 ...    ..( 25 skipped).    ..  *********************
 441    2016-01-18 15:16    40  *********************
 442    2016-01-18 15:17    41  **********************
 443    2016-01-18 15:18    40  *********************
 444    2016-01-18 15:19    40  *********************
 445    2016-01-18 15:20    40  *********************
 446    2016-01-18 15:21    41  **********************
 447    2016-01-18 15:22    40  *********************
 448    2016-01-18 15:23    40  *********************
 449    2016-01-18 15:24    41  **********************

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read: Disabled
          Write: Disabled

Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  4            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  4            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  4            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  4            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  4            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  4            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  4        48982  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  4            0  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  4            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000d  4            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0010  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, non-CRC
0x0012  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x0013  4            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, non-CRC
```

**Edit 14/04/2016:**
3 monthes later... Finally I replaced the original 320 Gb TOSHIBA MK3261GSYN by a Western Digital 500 Gb WD5000BPKX (I restored the original partitions and system, windows has only installed a new driver at the first reboot).

This has solved the latency problem, I don't fear opening Word or Visual Studio any more (although windows experience Index hasn't changed !).

However, smartctl still shows this "Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy" counter increasing at 2/seconds.

```
C:\windows\system32>smartctl -l sataphy /dev/sda
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [i686-w64-mingw32-win7(64)-sp1] (sf-6.4-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  2         8736  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            2  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x8000  4         7019  Vendor specific
```

I give up, I understand neither what this counter exactly is, neither what causes it to increase.

Comment: Backup now (if you can). Check the SATA cable is fully connected. Post the rest of the SMART results. [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: Almost certainly, PhyRdy is "physical ready", and PhyNRdy is "physical not ready". Your system's hard disk is glitching in and out for some reason. **Right now, back up any data that you at all care about.**

Comment: DavidPostill and Michael Kjörling : thank you very much for these quick answers, back up in progress. Sounds like I need to change my hard drive. I'll edit my question to include the whole smart report asap.

Answer (score 2):

This counter in itself is pretty inconclusive, SATA specs are paywalled, but the publicly-available [errata](https://www.sata-io.org/specification-errata-technical-proposals-and-design-guidelines) define it as:

> **Identifier 009h**
>   The counter with identifier 009h returns the number of times the device transitioned into the
>   PHYRDYn state from the PHYRDY state, including but not limited to asynchronous signal events,
>   power management events, and COMRESET events. If interface power management is enabled,
>   then this counter may be incremented due to interface power management transitions.

So, on top of loss of signal errors in the link and resets all transitions from the orange->working state in this diagram might increase the counter:
[image: Device-HBA Power Combinations]
Which and how many of those occur depends heavily on the individual drive and both your hardware/software configuration. For example my new SSD with DevSleep rapidly increases the counter, whereas the old one and my HDDs do not.

---

Your old drive had several other worrisome values, though:
`Reallocated_Sector_Ct`, `Power-Off_Retract_Count`, `Load_Cycle_Count` and `G-Sense_Error_Rate` all don't look too good, so replacing it was ok.