# Frequently getting message about corrupt recycle bin

Tags: windows, windows-10, external-hard-drive, file-corruption, recycle-bin

I keep getting the error message `the recycle bin on E is corrupt` and asks if I would like to delete it. Regardless of what I choose, the error message popsup every 10 or 15 minutes. E: is an external hard drive.

[image: error message]

I've also noticed I randomly loose permission to read from the drive, and have to re-run WD Unlocker.

I tried following [this solution](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/recycle-bin-is-corrupted-windows) but get the error "The directory is not empty"
`rd /s /q E:\$Recycle.bin` Also I can't see the recycle bin when I navigate to it in Explorer.

I'm running Windows 10 64bit and the hard drive is a WD Passport. I had upgraded from Windows 8.1 and never had any trouble with it.

UPDATE:

I tried running check disk but wasn't able to:

> Chkdsk was executed in scan mode on a volume snapshot.
>
> Checking file system on E: The shadow copy provider had an error.
>   Check the System and Application event logs for more information.
>
> A snapshot error occured while scanning this drive. You can try again,
>   but if this problem persists, run an offline scan and fix.

I tried running HD Tune for SMART test but am unsure if I ran it correctly, here are the results:

[image: screen shot]
[image: screen shot]
[image: screen shot]

I can use the drive fine, it's just this random error message saying the recycling bin is corrupt on it.

This was a scan with the WD propitiatory utility and show's no problems
[image: screen shot of WD Drive Utilities]

Comment: Check your hard drive for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: Given the repetition rate, it might also be that the external drive goes offline when not in use (a.k.a. sleep, low-power mode etc) but there is a miscommunication and Windows doesn't realize. Maybe check the WD site and see if there is any firmware update for your model.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have done so, is what I added what you want?

Comment: @Celeritas Can you include a screenshot of the "Health" tab?

Comment: @DavidPostill done, not sure how to interpret results?

Comment: @DavidPostill any thoughts?

Comment: @Celeritas Not sure. According to https://kb.acronis.com/content/9170: "This parameter is considered informational by the most hardware vendors. Although degradation of this parameter can be an indicator of drive aging and/or potential electromechanical problems, it does not directly indicate imminent drive failure. Regular backup is recommended. Pay closer attention to other parameters and overall drive health."

Comment: @Celeritas Wrong link see https://kb.acronis.com/content/9171 for S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: Used Reserved Block Count (Total). Explanation is the same.