# Windows 10 100% disk usage on startup and whenever opening Windows/Microsoft Native Apps

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-10, shutdown, services

Since earlier this week, my laptop becomes unresponsive when logging into windows. Disk C: is always at 100%. Windows will only be usable and lag free after around 15 mins. Open Resource Monitor shows me that these are usually the causes:
 pagefile.sys, softwaredistribution/datastore, app/data/local/comms/unistoredb/store

Also, my shutdown and boot times are prolonged. Booting would take 20 mins or more. The screen would get stuck at the manufacturer logo and the loading of windows.

I have already disabled windows apps from running in the background, disabled superfetch and windows search.

I have run full anti-virus scans and chkdsk scans, but they don't report any problems.

Logging onto different windows accounts doesn't solve it. I also removed my windows account and emails (mail and calendar apps)

All my drivers are up-to-date as well.

The last solution i haven't tried is doing a reset but as much as possible, i don't want to lose my installed programs

My machine: i5 processor, 4gb RAM, 1TB hard drive (Drive C: 209/372 GB, Drive D: 156/537)

Comment: By C: disk is always at 100%, do you mean the processor %? Or, the actual space left seen from `My Computer` is at  0? If this is processor usage, you need to isolate the application causing this.  You've mentioned pagefile.sys, if so, try changing how much memory is paged: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Also check you hard drive for errors. I had a drive that would act like this and it eventually currupted.

Comment: Check your hard drive for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: @AaronLayfield by 100% I mean the active time/disk transfer rate, not the storage in My Computer. I have changed the paging memory values. Initial: 200 MB, Maximum size : 1393 MB but to no effect. I have identified the processes/services causing this which is coming from the Unistore folder but have no idea how to stop these at startup

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I checked for errors but none showed. Both in chksdsk and analyze for defrag

Comment: Same issue on my win 10 for months even after *several* full resets. Resolved recently *maybe* by win updates or *Piriform Defraggler* (x64,i7,12GB,1TB)