# Computer freezing unexpectedly?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash

I recently upgraded to Windows 10, but this problem started when I had Windows 8.
At random times the computer will completely freeze and require a restart. It is a work computer and it is connected to several networks. My connection to the networks is lost but so is my local connection. Whatever program I'm in will stop responding and I cannot open any files or other programs (including internet browsers, everything just lags).

Several times I have closed out of everything and restarted but most times the computer won't even restart properly. Restarts usually take a matter of seconds for Windows but it's stayed on the restart screen (with those little dots going round and round) for up to 10 minutes sometimes. I usually end up manually restarting it.

I can't pinpoint the freezing to a specific program because it has happened while I'm working in various programs (microsoft suite, autocad, etc.)

Is there something I can look into to see why my computer is doing this? It has happened consistently for a few weeks now.

Edit: I realize as a work computer, this is an IT problem. They have been notified and are getting me a new machine. For various reasons I still have to use this one for the next few weeks. I was hoping to find a temporary/permanent solution until then so my work can go on uninterrupted.

Comment: Have you upgraded from Wind 8 or it was a clean install of Win 10?

Comment: "It is a work computer" - Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: @DavidPostill trust me IT has been notified. Their solution is to get me a new PC but that will take some time due to scheduling availability. I have to use this machine for a few more weeks at least. I was hoping to find a solution so my work could get done uninterrupted until then.

Comment: If you hard disk is failing (as the symptoms suggest) there is nothing you can do. Please check your hard drive for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803) and [edit] the question to include the results.

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like your HDD is failing.

You can use Crystaldisk to see if your HDD is indeed failing [Download Link](http://crystalmark.info/redirect.php?product=CrystalDiskMark)

Your HDD probably has been making new bad sectors every day.

Bad sectors are not healthy, but also not fatal, they are way more common than you might think. Your HDD sees these sectors and labels them faulty. When your HDD gets more and more bad sectors over time, it is a big sign that your HDD is going to die really soon.

Always have a back-up by the way

If you are going to make a back-up, please stop using any OS on the drive. To make a back-up with the most success rate, use a live CD/USB with Clonezilla, then select a whole disk clone, this is the least stressful on your HDD. But make sure that the destination disk is the same or larger size than your source disk

I hope i answered your question!