# Computer Misbehaving

Tags: windows-7, freeze

1.5 years ago my computer started to losing its performance a lot.

At first i thought that a possible virus would be the issue,  so i searched everything on my computer to find for a virus, but i didn't,  anyway to be sure i formatted it. The problem however persisted.

My computer was lagging, was taking to long to respond and everything seems to be way slower than it used to be. Even my compiles,  since i am software engineer, are taking to long,  and the applications freezing at start,  which is bad.

After it boots, from the moment it logs in my account  i have no control of it,  for like 45 seconds.  Everything freezing... And an interesting fact is that cpu usage is 3-5 percent...

Also one interesting fact is that on chrome some times it just takes to long to load some pages with the mysterious reason of "waiting for cache"

So i thought it should be a ram issue. So i ran memtest for my both 1600 crucial ddr3 8gb sticks,  and it came out clean. To be sure i ran the same test on a different rig, and the results were the same.

Weeks later I installed an antiviruus software,  VIPRE and even though its not that heavy. I lost the complete control of my computer. At random times,  my computer was just stopping to be responsive and even on ctrl alt delete it couldn't appear the screen, and it was giving me an error on a message box. So i had to uninstall the Antivirus.

So after all these i was confident its something about the cpu or the mobo's Northbridge,  Until today.

Today i got a special trojan which i removed instantly, it stopped some of my built in security services so i reenabled them and the i noticed i have some updates pending for my computer. So i gone for them. Now before it even started installing them at the time of downloading i got massive lag on my desktop,  i ignored it and tried to backup some of my projects on one of my hdds,  and just to populate all the files in the folder it took like 5 minutes and started copying them with 1.8MB/s...

So i said again maybe my hdd os faulty,  lets try over network. I have to admit over network improved a bit but still while i was transfering the data from my ssd to a network drive with 5MB/s the HDD on a separate network drive was going 80MB/s read / write.

So at this point i realized it could be a faulty ssd after all. But then again,  it could also be the Northbridge.

My cpu whatsoever passed every burntest, also all its benchmarks were quite good.

And with 0% load it operates at 23 Celsius while on avg load it operates at 30 celsius.  My specs:

Cpu i5 2500k,

Mobo Asus p8z68 deluxe

Ssd SanDisk sdssdp128g

Ram 2x crucial ballistix 1600 ddr3 8gb

Do you have any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: As is, your question is *really* hard to read and to understand. You might need to reformulate the question

Comment: Hi Devian, I don't know that anyone's going to try to read through all this. If you want a response, at least format the text so one can bother to read it all.

Comment: Sure i will do this tommorow beacuse my im on my phone. And its a bit hard atm.  Thanks for the tip though

Comment: Sounds like it could be a drive / SATA controller issue to me. Look in the system event log... any disk / ATAPI warnings or errors in there?

Comment: Did you try to start a live edition of Linux? I mean if it is virus related you will notice immediately and maybe you can fall in love of Linux too :) Moreover you can made some different tests.

Comment: Failing disk? Check your hard drive for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: @DavidPostill All my drives  according to Hard Disk Sentinel are 100% Healty and 100% Performance. SSD's Smart was perfect. No errors

Comment: @Hastur i case you didn't noticed, i Formatted my Drive and Reinstalled windows, and problem persisted even on a clean copy of windows. It's not about the operating system. This computer is for developing Windows Applications.

Comment: @BrianC No ATAPI Warnings neither Errors.

Comment: Another Remarkable thing is that on Task manager, Resource Monitor, on the Memory Section. Some times the Hard Faults are going 100% for a long period. Which is impossible since with that much hard faults it should be throw a BlueScreen, and the rams are perfectly fine. I did tried other rams too with the same result. That's why i first thought of Northbridge.

Comment: @Devian No I didn't guess, you should write explicitly that you reinstalled. Moreover to format it is not the same than to reinstall (you can copy or clone a partition and copy back after, you can format a partition simply to mark all the bad sectors and defrag when you copy back in a single solution...) BTW You excluded that it's an OS problem without testing with another one A Live version of Linux can help to find the solution ( [stresslinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/),  [inquisitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisitor_%28hardware_testing_software%29) or whatever you want to try).