# Laptop takes more than an hour to boot

Tags: lenovo-laptop

When I press the power button, the leds turn on, the fan works, and then it stops, and right after the leds turn on but the fan stays shut. The screen is black all along. And after an hour or so, it finally show "Lenovo" brand on the screen and works perfectly from this point forward.
What di you think might be failing ?

Comment: Check your hard drive for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)