# Questions regarding computer freeze (no BSOD)

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, bsod

My pc (win7 x64) randomly freezes (nothing responds only solution is a hard reboot) usually once a day sometimes it goes for 5 days with no freeze.

Steps I've taken so far:

- Updated all drivers from their official websites
- Memtested RAM
- Monitored temperatures/fan speed to see if theres any correlation to the freeze (all within norm)
- Re-slotted components in case of bad contacts
- Looked trough event viewer for potential causes
- Tried to look for patterns in what I do before the freeze occurs so far seems pretty random
- There is no minidump file as the pc doesn't BSOD

What are possible causes for full freeze (caps lock led doesn't work for example)?
Am I correct in assuming a bad driver would cause a BSOD instead?

I suspect a faulty piece of hardware likely motherboard/psu but I have no idea how to find out for sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: Did so, no errors reported

Comment: USB 3.0, no, no, no. Also stress/stability tested CPU with prime95 and GPU with furmark no freezes.

Comment: Ok deleted that, missed the part about this being a total lock-up requiring hard shutdown.  What is the motherboard & processor? And all the rest of the specs of the hardware.   Do you use a UPS?

Comment: Replaced motherboard problems stopped. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

Please read this wiki to find out how to find and upload your event viewer logs
answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/event-viewer-what-is-going-on-in-your-computer/fdda2010-d4df-4fed-863b-89ce0142419d