# Windows 10 stalls when starting app

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 is installed on my business critical workstation.  I find it rich with bugs, but the most annoying is application fail to start in a timely manner.  For example, Disk Manager takes 10 minutes to start, virtually any application except "office applications" which run perfectly.  The splash screen opens and then the application hangs.  Task manager shows no activity.  I have spent 8 hours with Microsoft support and none of their solutions work.  PC configuration consists of ASUS Z97 Mother board, Intel I7-4771, 32 GB DDR3 memory, EVGA GT 740 Video board, DVD Drive (2), RAID 5 3.995 TB, etc.

Comment: The only time i have seen applications taking awhile to open is when the system has a HDD that is starting to fail and the wait is cause by Windows waiting on I/O events.  Your problems have nothing to do with Windows 10 though, your problems, would happen in any version of Windows.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: We use an SSD 500 GB, brand new (Crucial Memory).  I have also tried to restart the system on other drives with the same results.

Comment: Problem solved with OS reinstall, I am not sure what the real issue was but it is now working perfectly.  Sorry for the delay in replaying.