# Windows 10 freezes

Tags: windows-10

In January of this year, I did a clean install of windows 10 on my laptop. Since then, it has been randomly freezing about 2 to 3 times a week. Before that I had Linux Mint on it and before Mint I had Windows 7. I have seen a lot of questions about this but not many answers. Here is what I have tried:

1. Did not help.

   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth

   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
2. I checked for a bios update. I am running the latest version.
3. I tried turning off PCI Express Link State Power Management. This did not help either.

It is an Acer Aspire 5750-9460. I never got it to un-freeze but maybe I am just impatient. Usually I just hard poweroff my computer.

Comment: Does anything get logged in the event log? I have a pc that periodically freezes, in win 10, and it blames the nvid driver. I believe it because the screen goes black. :)
I had to hard reset to get it back, 2 hours was the longest I left it.
But if the event log has nothing, I am not sure how one would troubleshoot much more.

Comment: I would think it is a driver also, but it is hard to tell with out more details.  If you don't see anything in the logs you might look in the device manager and see if there are any drivers with issues.  Win10 likes to use a lot of generic drivers, so you may want to look up video, sound and the mobo manufacturer's drivers and update all of them if you haven't already.  Any details on any errors would be really helpful.

Comment: How old is it? You might want to check your hard disk status. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: @MusselmanLLC interesting I will look into that.

Comment: @DavidPostill it's a new ssd as of January. A pretty well regarded one too I believe.

Comment: @Seeds I have one critical error in the event log whose source is `Kernel-Poser`. Is this relevant?

Comment: I am not familiar with `Kernel Poser`

Answer (score 0):

I have a Acer Aspire 5750 running Windows 8.1 Pro that randomly freezes. Tried all the usual bios, temp files, app uninstalls, power setting changes and it still freezes.
I tried a last ditch effort, as I suspect it is a graphics card/motherboard issue on this model. 
My 5750 only froze when Windows was not being used for a while and required a reboot.
If you don't use your computer even for a few minutes, or make a coffee etc. just press the power button to turn off screen (turns black) and press again to return to your page. (may require a signin) 
A quicker method is go to power options, change plan settings and set "turn off display" for 1 minute and save settings.
Since doing this, I have had no problems for several weeks now and I previously had 2-3 freezes per week.