# Windows Explorer freezing everything else

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Windows 7 x64, fully patched.
This just started hours ago. Opening up Windows Explorer is very slow. It takes about 30 seconds (if it actually opens) with nothing pegging the CPU or memory in Task Manager. All other windows pretty much stop responding. I just had to go into Task Manager and end all "explorer.exe" processes just so I could finish this post. At that point Windows Explorer would never open, just froze everything else.
I've had this computer for a few months and never had an issue. To start troubleshooting, I disconnected all USB drives and mapped network drives. So we're down to local drive C: which is an SSD. I have 8 GB of RAM and an i7 2.9 GHz CPU. Never had any issues and was happy with this laptop. This just started happening without anything installed or removed. No system changes took place.

Comment: do you use MSE as Av suite?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Answer (score 0):

In case any system files have become corrupt you could run the 'sfc /scannow' command in an elevated command prompt.

If that doesn't work I'd suggest running a full anti-virus scan in safe mode.