# System is copying files forever

Tags: windows-8.1

Sometimes I find that my system has trouble with copying task. Even I cancel all tasks it still shows status "*Canceling*" forever and only system restarts solves problem.

Why this happens ? How to solve this problem without system restart ?

[image]

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run some system tools like Disk Cleanup and Disk Defragmenter to speed up things.

It's possible that there's a bad cluster on  your hard drive that prevents it from copying.

You can also try breaking the files and copy them in chuncks.

Another thing, hit CTRL+SHIFT+ESC before you want to copy/paste something. Select Performance and start the copy paste. Check for flat lines. If any, there's a problem. If none, then it has to do with the content that you're copying and the location to where you're pasting.

Comment: These are ideas but not an answer and should be in the comments.