# Hard disk makes strange 'semi rotary' noise but laptop works fine.

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop

The exact nature of the sound is like the one made by phones with dials (remember those?) when small numbers like 1,2 and 3 are dialed. The noise is audible only when there is good amount of silence, like post 10pm, and seems to happen when idle.

The laptop works as though there is no problem. The only strange behavior I have noticed is it had shut down overnight a couple of times (usually it sleeps and goes to post sleep, hibernate I guess, but won't shut down).

This is my development laptop and is five years old. It is a Dell Inspiron 15 R with Windows 7 64bit Home Premium. Lately I have been doing web front end development actively which involves lot of saving .js files and refreshing .html files in the browser(Firefox 42). I suspect that it is still better than Visual Studio building C++ files wrt wear and tear on the hard drive when I could actually hear it churn. Also, I treat my laptop with respect, so won't hold it in odd positions etc. It is basically a laptop on a desk.

Anyone with similar experience?
**Is the hard disk failing or is it harmless?**

Comment: The sound is not harmless.  The HDD likely is indeed failing.  There are numerous applications that report the health of the drive based on it's S.M.A.R.T data.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the links. I downloaded and ran HD Tune Pro. The health status for all rows is 'ok'. Does it mean I can safely ignore the sound or are there more tests necessary?

Comment: And quick scan shows no errors as well (all green).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for *us* to know.  However, there area ways for *you* to find out.
From a `Command Prompt` type:

> wmic
>
> diskdrive get status

This should alert you to any errors.

However, you can always download a more advanced [GUI](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html), and it will give you far more information.

Comment: I know very well that there is no way for _you_ to know. I was just looking for some pointers and insight from people who encountered similar situation. Thanks for the suggestions though, I'll check them out.