# SATA Hard Drive Appearing/Disappearing and Files Not Accessible

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10

I'm not sure the original problem is relevant, but I did post a question about the same drive here:

[Added Hard Drive, Windows 10 No Longer Boots](https://superuser.com/questions/1082169/added-hard-drive-windows-10-no-longer-boots)

A friend lent me a SATA enclosure to try to recover the data from the drive.  Now I connect and turn on the drive after boot.  The drive appears in Windows Explorer.  When I click on it, it hangs for a good 30 seconds and then shows me its contents (one folder).  I try to copy the folder to a fully functional drive, and it starts the copy.  According to Windows, data *is* being moved.  After a few minutes, it fails saying the file (the first file it tries to copy) is not accessible.  At this point the drive usually disappears from Windows Explorer completely.

It may or may not be relevant, but the drive feels pretty warm to the touch.  Not nearly hot enough to burn, but warmer than I would expect, especially since 60% of the drive is sticking out of the enclosure.

It's not the end of the world if I don't recover the data.  It's just ripped DVD media--I would like to recover it if I can, since the DVD ripping process is so time consuming.

Anything else I can do to try to recover the media outside of taking it to a professional?

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: You probably have bad sectors.  Windows has chkdsk /R c:  which will scan and hide the bad sectors.  Another solution buy spinrite from grc.  This will actually to try to mathematically reconstruct the sectors.  Some sectors will be so damaged they can't be recovered but some maybe recoverable.