# Why do I need to run Winsock Reset every day?

Tags: windows-10

I know there are answers out there to this question, but that's just the problem - there are so many answers to so many similar (but not quite the same) situations that I am overwhelmed. So here is my situation.

Every day, at some point, my computer suddenly stops working properly. Here are all the things it does which I've noticed so far:

- Google Chrome stops functioning suddenly. It doesn't freeze, but it can't open anything that isn't already open (ie. I can still click between open tabs and see pages that are already open, but I can't hit "back" or "refresh")
- Edge functions well enough, but runs slower than normal and won't let me access any Microsoft websites
- Edge again, when it starts up it is in its default state, offering to give me the "first time" tour of Edge. All my favourites, history, and settings are gone.
- Everything runs a bit slow, in general
- I can't access any sort of administrative tools. Control panel opens up, but when I try to open anything from it, it just hangs.
- I can run cmd, but I can't run it (or anything else) as administrator

After I hit reset or shut down, it takes about 10-15 minutes for the computer to shut down. When it finally turns back on again I have this situation (I have never explored much at this point):

- After entering my password to sign in I either 1) get a blue screen telling me that Windows failed to connect to some service (this is rare, I can never quite catch which service before the screen disappears) then get signed out, or 2) when I sign in I get a message that Windows failed to connect to the Group Policy Client service.
- Since the only effective, simple, and straightforward solution I've found so far in my searching has been `netsh winsock reset`, I try to open cmd as administrator, but it usually doesn't open.
- I still can't access any administrative tools
- Google Chrome hangs for 20-30 minutes before opening. It works in an acceptable way for looking for troubleshooting help after that, but can't access Microsoft websites.
- Edge still functions the same as before (it works, but no Microsoft websites)

I usually have to reboot at least 1 more time. If that doesn't help I just keep rebooting until I can open cmd as administrator and run the `winsock reset` command. Once I can do that, I reboot and everything is back to normal.

I'm not the best with network stuff on my personal computer, but here's some information (feel free to ask for more in the comments):

- There are 3 more computers attached to the network here. None of the others have this problem.
- Details: **Windows 10 Home, Version 1511, Build 10586.494, on a Dell Inspiron 3847, Intel i5**.

So, `winsock reset` works as a band-aid and has been working for the past 6 months that I've been dealing with this (2-3 times a week). However, in the past 2 weeks(ish) this has become a daily process - and taking up to an hour to get my computer running every day isn't cool. So **why is this happening?** and **How do I fix it permanently?**

**UPDATE**

After a couple of Windows updates this behaviour stopped entirely. I haven't had it happen for about 6 months now. Thanks for all the advice in the comments and answers.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: I'll check that out and comment about how it goes.Thank @David

Comment: You may also have a corrupt user profile. Try creating a new user.

Comment: Your problem description frequently tells us that you can't do things but doesn't tell us *why* you can't do them or what happens when you try. For example, "*I can run cmd, but I can't run it (or anything else) as administrator*" and "*it can't open anything that isn't already open (ie. I can still click between open tabs and see pages that are already open, but I can't hit "back" or "refresh")*". What does it mean to say you can't hit "refresh"? It isn't there? Or what? Why can't you do these things? How are you trying to do them and what happens when you try?

Comment: Hi @DavidSchwarz. Thanks for the comment. "Why can't you do these things" was my question! Don't steal it - stealing isn't cool! Anyway, I was just hoping that the list of things I couldn't do might catch the attention of someone who happens to know what those behaviours meant, or who has had the same experience. They were odd behaviours. I knew it would be a slightly obscure question and I didn't want to write more of a novel than I already did to explain what was happening. Sorry the question was unclear to you!