# Windows 8 KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR and CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED

Tags: windows-8, bsod, sony-vaio

My laptop is a Sony Vaio svf15318snw. It came with Windows 8 pre-installed.

Lately, I had been facing sudden shutdowns with Blue Screen of Death and a random error code.

Mostly the error was KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR or CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED.

The CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED also came up when I woke the pc from sleep.

I recovered the laptop from the original recovery discs but the error won't go away. They just popped up randomly.

I tried `chksdk C: /f /r` but It was stuck at 28% for 8 hours. I tried analyzing the minidumps and they pointed to BOOTVID.dll and nvpciflt.sys so I thought the Nvidia drivers were causing it so I uninstalled the drivers but no luck.

Now I can't even recover it since the recovery process gets stuck in middle or it gives me a disk error.

I have a project to submit. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: The OS (Win 8) is totally corrupted because the recovery process didn't complete. Is there a live or bootable utility ?

Comment: See [Can I use Ubuntu to diagnose hard drive or RAM problems in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/q/317241) for how to do that from a live Ubuntu CD

Comment: Indeed - KERNEL DATA INPAGE ERROR almost always means disk errors.

Comment: http://imgur.com/oiqNEZx 
http://imgur.com/kS6k6oq
Disk seems okay.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error. A malware detector suggested "`du77a.exe`".

I used File Explorer to find it and delete it, and the problem has since not reoccurred.