# Can't copy files off internal hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 500GB Hitachi hard drive that for some reason, it won't let me copy files off of it. The little "transferring window" comes up and just freezes. How can I get my files off of that hard drive? I'm suspecting that the hard drive may be "dead", is that correct or plausible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to run the command "C:\>chkdsk /f c:" Is your HDD at capacity or near capacity? That could cause a lot of havoc also.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

ddrescue - Get a linux boot distro and use (gnu) ddrescue ti copy data off the drive. If it fails/gies slow, restartbit in reverse. Repeat until all data recovered ir you run out of patience.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, sounds like it's failing or started to fall. Try to use a tool like `dd` to create a image with everything you can without trying to write data to it (which might be part of the reason it freezes).

If you've got Linux it should be available by default or in your repository. A version for Windows cab be obtained here: http://chrysocome.net/

The basic idea is to create a full image as soon as possible, then work off that to get your data.