# Creating partitions on a drive with '4kb on bad sectors'

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

Here is what I am trying to do:

I want to install Linux on a 5-6 years old laptop. There are 4 primary partitions, so I am trying to create logical partitions into an extended partition.

I am using GParted Live to manage the partitions. So I wiped the current Windows partition in order to create the extended/logical partitions (in the meantime I heard the existence of 'fixparts'... that's another story).

When I tried to format the newly created volume to NTFS (didn't try another filesystem), I got an 'Input/output error'. So I just restored the disk image I created before messing with the partition table. I then ran 'chckdsk' in an elevated command prompt in Windows and it reported '4kb in bad sectors'. I also checked the option to repair the disk in the Windows utility afterwards. There is still 4kb in bad sector.

Is the bad sector the reason why it failed to create the partition? If so, what can I do about it?

Does that mean that there drive is slowly dying?

**EDIT:**

Here are a few output from SMART monitoring tools:

http://pastebin.com/tSwb7tQZ
http://pastebin.com/Bp7yVQw9

Seems OK to me.

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: I edited my question with the results