# HDD is seen in BIOS and seen as storage device but never able to boot windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, storage

So I had been literally trying to fix my windows not being able to boot at all for more than 24 hours straight till now. I almost read every single article and troubleshooting step on the web to find a solution but nothing seems to work. I will keep it short as much as I can.

I did all of the following and it was:

```
"Reset this PC" gave an error "The required drive partition is missing"

"Refresh this PC" gave an error "The drive where windows is installed is locked. Please unlock and try again"

"System restore" gave an error something I don't actually remember but its like "Choose your OS and then try again"

"Automatic Repair" just failed to fix it and reverted me back to advanced options.
```

After all of that, I did

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
bcdboot d:\windows (D is where I have the windows installed and C is for system reserved)
bcdboot d:\windows /s c: /f ALL
```

All of these command prompt lines failed giving multiple errors like:

```
For REBUILDBCD, it said "Identified total windows installations: 1" then clicked "Y" to add it to the list and then it said "The requested system device cannot be found"

For bcdboot d:\windows it said Failure when attempting to copy boot files"
```

I wiped the disk multiple times using diskpart and installed fresh copies of windows on it 3 times but each time the installation will finish stage 1 (at a very slow pace) then when it restarts to continue installation, it simply won't boot (Windows logo and a spinning dot circle below forever)

I gave up and tried a totally new HDD and installed windows to it, it booted so normal and fast actually so I made sure it was not an issue with the windows.

Now I am booted from the new HDD and reformatted the old HDD and working on data recovery using easeus and it is finding my stuff luckily. It is also noticeable that the old HDD is making some noise while it is reading now as I scan for lost files.

My ultimate question is, will this HDD ever be able to used again? Even as a storage drive not as a drive I boot from? Because it is being seen through the bios boot menu and I see it in the disk management with healthy status. Can this HDD be fixed or I'm better off stop using it?

Here is a screenshot of the health status through SMART using HD Tune Pro:

[image]

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Do this apply to windows 8 as well?

Comment: Most of the tools listed in the above linked questions will work on pretty much any version of Windows.

Comment: alright can I do this during the current recovery session conducted by easeus recovery wizard or should I wait for it to finish then check?

Comment: Wait for it to finish.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the health status through SMART using HD Tune Pro [smartstatus](https://s17.postimg.io/x8e7ut30v/SMARTcheck.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Can this HDD be fixed or I'm better off stop using it?

You should back up this disk as it could fail at any moment. Replacement is advised.

> This is a critical parameter. Degradation of this parameter may indicate imminent drive failure. Urgent data backup and hardware replacement is recommended.

---

#### S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: Reallocation Event Count

> **Description**
>
> Reallocation Event Count S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates a count of
>   remap operations (transferring data from a bad sector to a special
>   reserved disk area - spare area).
>
> The raw value of this attribute shows the total number of attempts to
>   transfer data from reallocated sectors to a spare area. Unsuccessful
>   attempts are counted as well as successful. Since this is a count
>   value, it can only increase. Recommendations
>
> This is a critical parameter. Degradation of this parameter may
>   indicate imminent drive failure. Urgent data backup and hardware
>   replacement is recommended.

Source [S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: Reallocation Event Count](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9132)