# Understand S.M.A.R.T Results for my HDD scan

Tags: hard-drive, boot, hardware-failure, smart

Can anyone around here tell me if this HDD is failed or not? I already bought a new one and installed windows to it since the one in test failed to boot windows and I was never able to fix it.

Here are the data:

[image]

Comment: I've already answered this in your previous question. [HDD is seen in BIOS and seen as storage device but never able to boot windows](https://superuser.com/q/1124431)

Comment: Sorry for duplication. My bad @DavidPostill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, yes it's failing. 
*Back up any data off this disk immediately*

It's started reallocating sectors because they've failed to write - a hard drive has a reserved amount of sectors that it can write to, in case the original write fails.

However you'd not expect this to normally stop a disk booting right away, unless you've also lost some data which is required by the boot process

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/26842/can-i-trust-a-hard-drive-that-has-had-to-reallocate-sectors) question discusses nicely if you can 'trust' a drive that's started re-allocating. I'd personally remove all data off it and trust it only with throw away data that I have stored else where (maybe for carrying some movies around to a friends house or something) but nothing important.

Comment: Yeah I guess I will keep it for archival purposes for stuff that I already have backed up elsewhere. Thanks alot.

Comment: Keep it for things like movies,media, etc. stuff that won't break if a block of the file is failed. An archive will CRC-fail if a HDD block is bad.

Comment: Guess I will just secure erase it and sell it. Some stores here buy these old drives. Will the diskpart clean all command erase everything and make it unrecoverable?