# Can I be sure that my WD Passport Ultra 3.0 2 TB external hard drive is fixed?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

5 days ago Windows 10 Notifications section warned me that there were errors on my WD Passport Ultra 3.0 2 TB drive. I went to Properties and chose Check Disk twice and both times it took about 20 minutes but it said that it had fixed the errors. After trying to save additional files to the drive Windows 10 stated that the errors would only be corrected by check disk process after a system restart. I restarted my computer and have not had anymore problems. The Passport Ultra is only 15 months old. This concerned me greatly and I did not want to run the risk of loosing about 1TB of files so I transferred the majority of the files to two older drives that I do not use much anymore. 
I am considering reformatting the Hard drive using the old low level reformatting command this way if there are any bad sectors they will be locked out. Do or should I do this? Or was this a glitch in the system and I can rely on the WD drive as a reliable data storage device.

Some more background info. Before I started experiencing the "fix errors" notices my computer file explorer and internet experience was really bad. The computer was extremely slow at anything I tried doing. But once I removed the usb hub where the WD was attached my computer started working properly. I then plugged the WD Passport directly into my computer usb port and then received the "fix errors" messages from Windows 10.

Comment: When it comes to hard drives there is nothing that you can rely on as reliable.  Make backups.  You should have 2-3 copies of important data.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could have been related to the USB hub you've used since the slowness was fixed once you've plugged it directly to the PC.

At this point I'd suggest to run an additional health check with the manufacturer tool [Data Lifeguard Diagnostics](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en) and see what the results will be. You can run the Extended test because if the software finds anything wrong during that check it will try to fix it automatically, but don't forget to backup any important data before that in order to prevent any potential data loss.

Let me know how it went and feel free to upload some screenshots if you want so I can take a look. :)

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: Thank you @David for pointing it out! :) I don't know why sometimes the link doesn't work...

Comment: The redirect maybe? http://products.wdc.com/support/redirect.htm?redirect=http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en&utm_source=[Can I be sure that my WD Passport Ultra 3.0 2 TB external hard drive is fixed?](http://superuser.com/q/1128606)&utm_medium=Forum&utm_campaign=WD%20Community%20Engagement%20Tracking&utm_content=http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en&utm_term=Mighty_Miro_WD

Comment: I just get a blank page.