# Diagnosing hard drive lockup on Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

Intermittently I run into this situation on my Windows 10 work computer.

[image: Hard Drive with 100% utilization, 0kb/s read/write speed]

The entire machine locks up for something between 3-7 seconds, maybe more, in any number of processes, including windows explorer. There doesn't seem to be a specific process that is hogging the hard drive during this process, although the windows 'Antimalware Service Executable' might be the most commonly seen culprit.

How would I go about diagnosing this issue?

HDTune reads all clear. Worthwhile to note the computer locked up for a second during this 'update'.

[image: HDTune 'health' tab]

Comment: If you click the resource monitor you can see what is using your entire disk. but this can also be a sign that your hard drive is failing

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors http://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7, and http://superuser.com/questions/14803/what-is-the-easiest-method-of-checking-smart-status-for-your-hard-drive. Report back with the results.

Comment: I ran the Speedfan 'Short Test' and either get 'interrupted by reset', 'no error', and one time 'Unsupported??'. Suggestions?

Comment: You seem to use a lot of 3rd party utilities.  Are these approved by your company's IT department?  Are you allowed to install whatever software you wish?  My first reaction is, hardware issue, second is poorly written Java is doing cleanup (minecraft anyone?), third is malware.  Try the resource monitor.  Watch it especially during one of the times the hard drive usage is pegged.

Comment: @Xalorous There is no IT dept, this is a tiny company. This machine has been used by many previous hires and I'm pretty much left to my own devices on this.