# Other drive loads after minutes

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, performance

After my Windows 10 starts up, my non-system HDD (WDC WD5000AZRX-00L4HB0) takes a few minutes to load. Until that, my shortcuts there are white, and if I try to open the drive in win explorer, it freezed (win explorer) until the drive "wakes up".

I don't know how relevant this is but:
I have installed Win 10 about half a year, it was not activated for approximately 2 months. After activating + 1 month this problem started to appear.

I used HD Tune for SMART scan:
[image]

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a matter of memory overstocking. Have you added a lot of data over recent months to your external drive? If you have, I would rather blame it on CPU capacity.
I use external drive on my Panasonic touchbook, and the story it's just the same. It runs lickety-split when empty, but gradually slows down as it gets filled with data.

Comment: this is not an external drive it is connected via SATA