# “This PC” in Windows Explorer is suddenly very slow

Tags: windows-explorer

I am using Windows 10 64 bit Pro and somehow last night my Windows Explorer started to hang, taking a really long time to load “THIS PC.” I also noticed that two of my network drives became inaccessible.

In order to troubleshoot I have:

- Disabled network sharing (through control panel, disabling File & Printer sharing on both private and public access).
- Reset all the folder options to default, thinking maybe the issue was coming from a folder that I had recently changed the folder optimization to.
- Disabled all options in the Privacy section of Quickaccess and clicked the Clear button
- Performed Windows Memory Diagnostic (returned no errors).
- Performed `sfc /scannow`. Windows found corrupt files and corrected them.
- Disabled Windows Search in `msconfg` (then rebooted).
- Checked drives with [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) software (there was one drive with errors but I unplugged it and the problem persists).
- preformed a `netsh winsock reset` with admin privileges
- Unchecked all drives and directories in Windows Indexing

When none of my attempts described above worked to fix the issue, I did several System Restore (at different points in time where there were no issues), but the problem persists.

**What did work**

Creating a new account seemed to resolve the issue, but alas I dont want to move to migrate all my data over to a new account. Can any one explain what this is indicative of?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: This can happen by connected USB devices (e.g. smartphones) in case the USB connection is defective (bad or too long cable).

Comment: @DavidPostill im on WIndows 10

Comment: Doesn't matter. Those SMART tools run on any version of Windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did find a drive with errors, but unplugged it and rebooted. Removing the bad drive did not fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours and hours of trying countless things I finally figured it out. The reason why Explorer was hannging was that there were two network drives that were still present in "THIS PC" that was activated by the Winaero tweak 'Customize THIS PC Folders' option.

Even though the network drive connections were disabled, their icons were still present in the THIS PC. Removing them with Winaero solved the issue immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason was **Google Drive**. Something happened to its permissions, so it could not open. As soon as I uninstalled the google drive, the File Explorer now opens very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was **Fusion360**. It created some sort of network folder in This PC that was slowing things down dramatically. I didn't need Fusion360 anymore so I just uninstalled it and that fixed the issue.