# HDD 100% active time, no disk activity. Unspecified error reported in chkdsk. System hangs a lot

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

**The problem:**

My system hangs a lot when doing certain tasks (ambiguous). Whenever my system hang and I check my system resource performance, it usually is the 1 TB secondary HDD, Seagate, aka Drive E, running at 100% active time with little to no actual disk activity/disk transfer. Often times I couldn't even restart the machine properly as it just keep perpetually trying to shutdown and I have to pull the plug to turn it off. Other times everything seem to be perfectly fine. So I replaced the suspect HDD before failure and now, a little more than a year thereafter I get the same issue with my new HDD, even though the problem seem to be less frequent, it seem to be increasing over time.

**What I have done:**
I have scanned both HDD with at least two third party tools and every report was positive. I don't remember for sure if I ran chkdsk on the previous HDD, but on the new HDD chkdsk fail with "unspecified error" every time, right after "Correcting errors in Volume Bitmap". I get the same unspecified error. Defragment cannot be completed (stuck with the same 100% active time with no disk activity). I read on some thread that setting the power management to high performance solve the problem for some people, it didn't work for me. Some people suggested that it could be due to malware attack and there's still a chance that is the cause of the problem, but so far a full scan cannot be completed.

**Log from event viewer:**

```
Checking file system on E:

Volume label is Data.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  92928 file records processed.      
 File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 940.38 milliseconds.
  75 large file records processed.  
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.           
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.83 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  948 reparse records processed.      
  105706 index entries processed.        
 Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 14.36 seconds.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 18.71 milliseconds.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 5.01 milliseconds.
  948 reparse records processed.          
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 8.65 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Cleaning up 1 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 1 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 1 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 23.61 milliseconds.
  6389 data files processed.     
Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.21 milliseconds.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
Write failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0xbe6a0000 for 0x20000 bytes.
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e 15e1).
Write failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0xbee40000 for 0x20000 bytes.
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e 17ff).
```

**Chkdsk result:**

[image: CMD screenshot]

Comment: **NT Status** 0xC0000185 (-1073741435)

**Windows Error** 0x45D (1117)



**NT Status Message:** - The I/O device reported an I/O error. 
**Windows Error Message**:  - The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: The answers work for Windows10 as well.