# Windows Explorer is sluggish, bringing apps down with it

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-explorer

My PC has been acting up recently. Windows Explorer is really slow sometimes (e.g. it takes 5-7 seconds to open a folder) and it makes apps lock up too whenever I open a file through the Open File menu and it decides to lag.

The sluggishness is there no matter what the storage/app I'm using is: whether it's my local server, my external HDD or my internal SSD, Explorer itself or an app with the Open File menu open - it still does this.

At first I thought it might be a system file corruption (because I had it happen on an older PC of mine), so I ran SFC and DISM. After a restart, the problem was still there. I ran the tools a couple more times just to be sure, but to no avail.
*(I have to note though that SFC did successfully fix a more serious issue I had some months ago, though it was totally unrelated to this one. ...So why it just gives up on Windows Explorer?)*

Since I really want to avoid reinstallation, is there anything that can be done to fix Windows Explorer?

Comment: Have you ran a virus scan? This could be a result of malware.

Comment: Could be a failing disk. Please run SMART tests on all of your disks. [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). [Edit] your question with the results.

Comment: Do you have Dropbox installed? Or any other [shell extensions](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)?

Comment: @J.Mini I run virus scans periodically, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm on Windows 10 and always have HDSentinel enabled. It says the disks' health is perfect.

Comment: @user1686 Only MEGAsync and OneDrive (which comes included). Though the problem started a couple months after I installed MEGAsync.

Comment: Could be a refurbished machine, they do that when they get old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have checked for malware and checked you hardware and the problem remains, then it is probably a shell context extension issue with Windows File Explorer.

You have run DISM / SFC without success. These two tools do not fix context issues.

It is possible that there is an issue with the Windows User Profile.  Make a new, test, Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Account and test.

Otherwise, there are so many contexts that the most practical way to solve the issue is with a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair and proceed
> normally. Use the option to Keep Everything to begin with. The repair
> takes about an hour after download.
>
> If Keep Everything does not work, Keep Data, and Keep Nothing
> (effectively Windows re-installation) are more aggressive steps.

.

**Follow up:**

When all the testing is done, it is faster in my experience to reinstall Windows than to pull out the needed bits of a damaged profile and recreate a clean profile.

Your comment indicates a profile problem. So either create a new profile (much time) or reinstall Windows (faster).

Your other comment suggests you will upgrade to Windows 11 and make Windows 10 work truly properly first is the best approach.

Comment: I tested Explorer on a different user account. No problems there. The thing is, though, that it does not happen all the time, so I'll have to wait for Explorer's "lag time".

Comment: That means it is a profile problem. You can try backing up your profile and then recreate your profile and set it up. Lots of work. The Keep Nothing approach above is essentially a reinstall and is faster in my experience than saving details of user profiles to put in a clean profile.

Comment: I'll probably recreate my profile when I have the time. I have one more question though: I've been planning to upgrade to Windows 11 for a while. Will the upgrade automatically fix my profile or will I also have to recreate it there?

Comment: No. Upgrade to Windows 11 is like a Repair Install and keeps your profile. Upgrading to Windows 11 will leave you with the same problem. Really, if you are going to upgrade (I have Windows 11 running) make sure Windows 10 is working well and in my experience and the state of your machine, Windows 10 reinstall first is the best idea.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I have helped you so you might consider upvoting my answer