# Unable to move some videos from internal HDD to external

Tags: hard-drive, video

I have 2 HDDs in my notebook, in the second one I have a lot of videos (800 GB), some of them are just downloaded from the internet, others come from my drone, and from my smartphone, etc...
Now if I try to copy or move some videos I see the transfer speed goes down to 0 after some seconds and I have an error: "cannot read from source file or disk", but I can move the file inside the HDD and also open it with VLC (usually it is slow when I try to move forward with vlc).

I already see a similar question here and I already tried to rename the file, move it inside another directory, try to restart the pc, move every single file one at a time, and also try to run a check disk that gives me 0 error.

So what can I do.

UPDATE
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Renaming the file doesn't really move data. Guess: The HDD you are moving it to is damaged.

Comment: I try different pendrive, I think my internal hdd is damaged

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](http://superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: thanks for links, updated question, now I see this health screen

Comment: You need to read the first two columns of the SMART data. 100 is nominal, lower is worse. Raw data can be anything, I doubt you really have 9800 reallocated sectors, and if this is your source disk, it won't explain why it stops reading. So the real problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @dirkt So how do you explain the description at the bottom of the report?

Comment: Your tool assumes that the raw data is the number of re-allocated sectors. While this is often the case for this particular value, it needn't be. And if my harddisk had 9800 reallocated sectors (which is way over the reserve it actually has), the "Current" column would be way below 100.

Comment: @dirkt so how can I find the problem, I am going to lose 40-50 videos

Comment: You should back up the entire drive ASAP. Use `ddrescue` or a similar tool specialized in dealing with damaged storage devices/media. You can then use PhotoRec or a similar tool to try and recover what's left of your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved most of the problems by creating a Linux live USB and using `badblocks` command.
Now I can copy most of the videos so this helps me a lot and without spending money (but spending a lot of hours)

Answer (score 3):

#### I have an error: "cannot read from source file or disk"

Based on your SMART data your drive is failing. It has managed to reallocate 9800 sectors but has failed to reallocate another 16 sectors.

You should buy another drive and copy as much data as you can from this drive before it completely fails.

Comment: is it possible to recover the video that I can't copy? and is it possible to save the disk partitioning the bad sectors?

Comment: Probably not ...

Comment: If I scan for errors there is nothing, maybe I can save it in some way?

Comment: Would you risk having more files corrupted to avoid buying a new drive?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to copy files to another drive? It can help you to find out which drive has a problem.

Do you have the permission to move files? Maybe it is not shown that you are not able to.

Did not you drop the laptop or one of the disks?

Well, if you won't fix it, I think, the only way left is to record everything from the screen... But you better try to find the problem disk between these two and not to use it later.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have 800 gb of videos and I assume that 10/15% have this problem.
The drive with problems is D, and yes I have permission

Comment: Only 10-15%? Then it seems like the disk is out of its life and it is a normal thing. How long do you use it?

Comment: it is about 1 year

Comment: @mitts told a way to solve it, but I have Windows 10 and don't like Linux, so I can't tell you if it works. But you better not use this drive anymore and check if the disk defragmentation is turned off 'cause it hurts drives (HDD slowly, SSD fast). If you don't need to use these videos right now, you better not use it or, if you are able to do this, just record the videos you have. I see you ve got very mush video (the same for me) & you can try what mitts said, but know that the more you use problem driver the faster it can break, so be careful with some operations...

Comment: If the disk is on it works even if you don't use it. If you want to save your disk for a very long time you should extract it and use only when you do need. Otherwise, it slowly breaks. That is why I do like external HDDs...

Comment: No, killing disks is a feature peculiar to windows. I have disks with 5 years uptime, never "defragmented" and still test OK.

Comment: Also hard disks are not rated for archival data storage, so if you want your data "for a very long time" - make copies, frequently, and test their integrity regularly. Anything needing verylongtime storage should go to physical media, magnetic tape or BR/DVD being the best thing humans have come up with yet.

Comment: (sorry, just noticed your answers) Yes, disks are the best) Love it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is get the disk somewhere windows can't hurt it any more.

Then create an image of the disk. You will need another disk equal or greater capacity, and a *nix system.
The most ubiquitous tool would be `dd`.

Then remove the physical drive and set it aside.

Then you may mount the image and pull whatever files you can; and throw recovery tools at what files you can't pull.

Moving forward, know that all hard disks are consumable (backup); windows is bad at hard drives (avoid windows, or backup more) and NTFS (windows' file system) NEEDS to be overprovisioned so if you fill, or near-fill a drive, expect more errors sooner (avoid ntfs, or backup more)